# Power supply for single Eurorack module

Tags: hardware, power, powering

I am new to Eurorack modules and I ordered a Pittsburgh Lifeforms Percussion Sequencer (https://pittsburghmodular.com/store/lifeforms-percussion-sequencer). I read the online manual before ordering and thought the power supply would be easier for one single module.

Now I am unsure because of the +/-12V properties given in the manual. So can anybody answer if this would be a suitable power supply: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B076JNGLC6/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

If not, does anybody have a better suggestion? All I can find are 16pin cables on Schneider's Laden or directly from Doepfer, but again, I'd like to power this single module only.

Answer (score 1):

Important Caveat - never worked with modular before, but...

Specs in the manual require +/- 12v only. No +5v requirement. Current requirements are +12v 150mA and -12v 45mA.

This is well within the specs (300mA) of the power supply you are proposing to purchase.

Comment: Great thanks, so this would be a good first try. However, this does not contain the actual cable for plugging it into a socket. Does it make a difference what I use from there?

Comment: the PSU docs do contain some mention of the ribbon cable required. It sounds like a standard modular synth component that all modules adhere to, so might probably be available as a separate part if it is not contained within the module hardware or the PSU hardware kits.

Comment: Most of the time, each module comes with a power cable. The cable will have on one end the 16 pin connector which will fit the power supply. The module end will be either 10 pins (for ±12V) or 16 pins (for modules which use +5V or the signal buses).